# How do I hash a formidable file object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I'm trying to use formidable's hash function to create a md5 hash, but I'm having a little trouble with the syntax.  Any tips would be helpful, its telling me that hash.digest has already been called (maybe when I call form.hash), but it seems like the formidable examples on github use a similar function.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, next){

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); 
form.hash = 'md5';

form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file){

    file.path = __dirname + '/data/uploaded_files/' + file.name;    
    console.log("File name extracted: " + file.name);
    res.locals.file_name = file.name;

});

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, file) //parsing through body parser
{
    var new_hash = file.hash;
    new_hash = new_hash.digest('hex');
    console.log("Hash generated");
    console.log(new_hash);
});
```

Comment: rename: option.hash into option.hashAlgorithm